# Apply conditional statement to every element in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, if-statement

I have the following code:

```
if (res[0].toString() == "hello") { res[0] = "string"; };
```

It works, but I would like to have it not just apply to the first element, but for every element.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Edit: Solved. Thanks people.

Comment: Can't you just use a loop? (Or `.map`)

Comment: do you mind showing the array and expected output?

Answer (score 2):

You could reassign a mapped value.

```
res = res.map(o => o === "hello" ? "string" : o);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 res = res.map(it => it === "hello" ? "string" : it);
```

or

```
for(const [index, value] of res.entries())
 if(value === "hello") res[index] = "string";
```

---

You probably won't need `.toString()` (I assume it's a string already) and always use `===` except you really know why `==` would be better (in very rare cases)

Answer (score 0):

That's a [`.map` operation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

```
const arr = [
  'hello',
  'World',
  'Hello',
  8,
];
arr2 = arr.map((el) => {
  if(el.toString() === 'hello') return 'string';
  return el;  // return the original unchanged
});
console.log(arr2);
```

will output

```
[ 'string', 'World', 'Hello', 8 ]
```